# Closed form Fibonacci Series

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, fibonacci

I am using Python to create a Fibonacci using this formula:

[image]

I have this recursive Fibonacci function:

```
def recursive_fibonacci(n):
if n <= 1:
    return int((((1 / (5 ** 0.5)) * (1 + (5 ** 0.5))) ** n) - (((1 / (5 ** 0.5)) * (1 - (5 ** 0.5))) ** n))
else:
    return(recursive_fibonacci(n - 1) + recursive_fibonacci(n - 2))
```

To display it I am using this:

```
nterms = 10

if nterms <= 0:
    print("Please Enter a positive integer")
else:
    print("Recursive Fibonacci Sequence: " ,
        [recursive_fibonacci(i) for i in range(nterms)])
    print("Iterative Fibonacci Sequence: " ,
        [iterative_fib(i) for i in range(nterms)])
```

How would I use an iterative function with this Fibonacci?

I've tried using this:

```
def iterative_fib(n):
    equation = lambda n: int((((1 / (5 ** 0.5)) * (1 + (5 ** 0.5))) ** n) - (((1 / (5 ** 0.5)) * (1 - (5 ** 0.5))) ** n))
    if n <= 1:
        return equation(n)
    else:
        a, b = 1, 2
        for i in range(n):
            fn = equation((i-a)+(i-b))
        return fn
```

However this iterative function doesn't seem to have the same output as the recursive function.

**The output of the recursive function:**

```
Recursive Fibonacci Sequence:  [0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68]
```

**The output of the iterative function:**

```
Iterative Fibonacci Sequence:  [0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6, 13, 27, 58, 122]
```

Comment: If you have a formula, why do you need either recursion *or* iteration?

Comment: I think(@Roman correct me if I am wrong), what he wants is to print all the values of f(n) starting from 0 to n. That's why he is iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation you're trying to implement is the [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) Fibonacci series.

Closed form means that evaluation is a constant time operation.

```
g = (1 + 5**.5) / 2  # Golden ratio.
def fib(N):
    return int((g**N - (1-g)**N) / 5**.5)
```

Contrast with,

```
def fib_iterative(N):
    a, b, i = 0, 1, 2
    yield from (a, b)
    while i < N:
        a, b = b, a + b 
        yield b
        i += 1
```

And we have

```
>>> [fib(n) for n in range(10)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
>>> list(fib_iterative(10))
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the expression  *f_n* for the Fibonacci sequence that you mention.

Notice that it is not a recurrence relation. It is a function of *n*, i.e., it provides the value of the *n*-th term when given an *n*.

Hence, you really don't have a recursive/iterative solution to generate the entire Fibonnaci sequence here.

Plugging in *n* as 0, 1, 2, 3.. provides the terms 0, 1, 1, 2, .. of the series.

To illustrate, when *n = 3*, f_3 is calculated as -
[image]