# Recursive Fibonacci with yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, fibonacci, yield

i am trying to build a Fibonacci function with yield here in this code, my 
problem is

> How to use yield in recursion and recursive calls

```
def fib(x):
  if(x==0 or x==1 ):
   yield  1
  else:
    yield fib(x-1)+fib(x-2)

y=[i for i in fib(10)]
print(y);
```

I get this error

---

> "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'"

I am in need to know how to use yield with recursion without get this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed form Fibonacci Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244630/closed-form-fibonacci-series)

Comment: Explained here in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244630/closed-form-fibonacci-series

Comment: My problem is not about Fibonacci  it's about using Yield with recursive calls  ,and recursion

Comment: The linked answer has multiple solutions including one with yield

Comment: i found the answer but the topic us not related yo yield it's about recursion.

Comment: Please explain why you have to calculate the Fibonacci numbers which are *the* textbook example for an iterative sequence via recursion?

Comment: the issue not about Fibonacci , it's about recursive calls with yields , i am just learned it and i was thinking to use it with a a recursive problem so i used Fibonacci to apply it

Answer (score 2):

You want the power to shoot yourself in the foot.

Well, here you go. 
Introducing "yield from" in python 3.3+ in [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)

"forward recursive yield"
(This will behave similar to how you would expect generators to behave.)

```
def fib_infinity(start = 0, acc = 1):
    yield start + acc
    yield from fib_infinity(acc, start + acc)

i = fib_infinity()
next(i) #1
next(i) #2
next(i) #3
next(i) #5
next(i) #8
```

Note that this will error out once the maximum recursion depth is reached.

This however does not really satisfy how we tend to think of a usual recursive function that tries to work downwards. However, it seems that we could simplify our recursive function to a tail recursive function, we could introduce yield and utilize it.

Attempt 2:
"backward recursive yield"

```
def fib(n, a = 0, b = 1): 
    if n == 0:
        yield a
    if n == 1: 
        yield b
    yield from fib(n - 1, b, a + b)

y = [next(fib(i)) for i in range(10)]
#[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

note however that we get our output in one "next" call. What happens now with a yield let loose?

```
i = fib(8)
next(i) #21
next(i) #21
next(i) #RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

We can make the function very slightly safer by introducing a return, for a final version.

Attempt 3: #safe for non-base cases.

```
def fib(n, a = 0, b = 1): 
    if n == 0:
        yield a
        return 0
    if n == 1: 
        yield b
        return 0
    yield from fib(n - 1, b, a + b)
i = fib(8)
next(i) #21
next(i) #StopIteration
```

I cannot think of a single scenario where you would want to create a recursive solution with yields, and the downsides of the setup seem immense. However, somethings are just meant to be explored for fun. This question made me curious enough to do some research on it. **I will advise however, to never actually do this.**

Comment: thank you for your answer , i was to know how to recurs with yield i am new in use it , yes i was try that for learn more and fun and i find that your Attempt  was easier to understand the idea , so thank you again